# Visual Studio - Unable to find a matching view in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

I get this error when I right-click on controller action method and select 'Go to view'

[image]

This is in Visual Studio 2017.

i am pretty sure that I have the folders set up correctly in terms of naming conventions etc.

So I have an action method called **'Index'** in **'MyMessagesController'** within **'Controllers'** folder.

And I have a view called **'Index.cshtml'** within **'MyMessages'** folder within **'Views'** folder. The **'Views'** folder is in same level as **'Controllers'** folder.

Can anyone help me on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was actually directory structure in the end. The structure is as follows:

[image]

So the controller I had was in MVCProject->MVC->Controllers.
The way it was mapped was that the view for it would be generated in MVCProject->Views.

But actually all the corresponding views were in MVCProject->MVC->Views and there was nothing in MVCProject->Views